# AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'ax'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'ax'

Comment: That line of code could not have produced the error you describe.  Please cut and paste the surrounding code as well.

Answer (score -1):

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x,y)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x)
```

Comment: FYI `plt.figure()` doesn't really do anything here. you're actually only plotting on the `plt.subplots()` axes.